# What restrictions on the form of an integral equation have a unique solution f=0?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, integration

We're stuck on the following question in a problem relevant to a physics paper on AdS/CFT that we are working on. Given a Fredholm equation of second kind with the form $f$+$\int_D K f\,dx = 0$, where $\int_D K f\,dx$ is not a contraction and $D$ is compact, what are some of the general cases in which $f=0$ is the unique solution?

Alternatively, what restrictions on $K$ does one have to put to obtain a unique solution?

Comment: If you write $Tf=\int Kf\, dx$, then you want $1+T$ to have trivial kernel, so $-1$ must not be an eigenvalue of $T$, and whether or not this holds will depend on small details, so there's not a whole lot you can say in this generality.

Comment: Is there perhaps some interesting subclasses of small detailed cases where this is true? Again, what (nontrivial) restrictions on $K$ could one put on equations of this form to get a unique solution?